# Evaluate env variable dynamically

Tags: linux, bash, awk

How to evaluate env variables dynamically ?

I'm copying the content of a file and replacing the values in it.
I came up with this for now :

```
awk -v FS="=" -v OFS="=" '$2="$"$1' source-file.txt > output-file.txt
```

Let's suppose we have two env variable, key1='toto1' and  key2='toto2'

The result :

```
source-file.txt  ----------------->  output-file.txt   ----------> expected output-file.txt           
key1=secret                          key1=$key1                    key1=toto1
key2=secret                          key2=$key2                    key2=toto2
```

How can I make it evaluate the value and print key1=toto1 rather than key1=$key1?

Comment: Not clear at all, could you please post more detailed sample of input and expected output and let us know then.

Comment: I updated the description

Comment: Never use an action as a condition unless you **need** the result of that action to be evaluated as a condition. Use `'{$2="$"$1} 1'`, not `'$2="$"$1'` to make your code clearer and remove any possibility of obscure errors creeping in. Also, when you have 2 variables that must have the same value, assign them together to that value, not separately, e.g. use `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}`, not `awk -v FS="=" -v OFS="="`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F= '{printf "%s=%s\n",$1,ENVIRON[$1]}' <source_file.txt >output_file.txt
```

This assumes that the variables (key1 etc.) are **really** environment variables (i.e. exported variables), as you stated, and not just shell variables.

Comment: `-v FS==` = `-F=`

Comment: @EdMorton: Thank you. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: It's not `-v -F=`, it's just `-F=`.